# Why is std::shuffle as slow (or even slower than) std::sort?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, c++11, shuffle

Consider the simple code that measures execution time and the number of swaps performed:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

struct A {
    A(int i = 0) : i(i) {}
    int i;
    static int nSwaps;

    friend void swap(A& l, A& r)
    {
        ++nSwaps;
        std::swap(l.i, r.i);
    }

    bool operator<(const A& r) const
    {
        return i < r.i;
    }
};

int A::nSwaps = 0;

using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
using std::chrono::duration_cast;
using std::chrono::milliseconds;


int main()
{
    std::vector<A> v(10000000);

    std::minstd_rand gen(std::random_device{}());
    std::generate(v.begin(), v.end(), [&gen]() {return gen();});

    auto s = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::sort(v.begin(), v.end());
    std::cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - s).count() 
        << "ms with " << A::nSwaps << " swaps\n";

    A::nSwaps = 0;
    s = high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), gen);
    std::cout << duration_cast<milliseconds>(high_resolution_clock::now() - s).count() 
        << "ms with " << A::nSwaps << " swaps\n";
}
```

The output of the program depends on the compiler and the machine, but they are quite similar in their nature. On my laptop with VS2015, I get 1044ms with ~100 million swaps for sort and 824ms with 10 million swaps for shuffle.

libstdc++ and libc++ do twice as few swaps for sort (~50M) and the results are as follows. Rextester gives me similar results: [*gcc*](http://rextester.com/SEJQZ64474) sort 854ms, shuffle 565ms, [*clang*](http://rextester.com/TXMD25534) sort 874ms, shuffle 648ms. The results shown by ideone and coliru are even more drastic: [*ideone*](https://ideone.com/i6lXCx) sort **1181ms**, shuffle **1292ms** and [*coliru*](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/626d45b719ec3a9c) sort **1157ms**, shuffle **1461ms**.

So what's the culprit here? Why with 5 to 10 times more swaps sort is almost as fast or even faster than a simple shuffle? I'm not even taking into account comparisons and more complex logic in `std::sort` including choosing insertion, heap or quick sort algorithms, etc. I doubt it's the random engine - I've even chosen the simplest one `std::minstd_rand` which basically does an integer multiplication and a modulo. Is it the cache misses that make shuffle relatively slow?

PS: the behaviour is the same for simple `std::vector<int>`

Comment: it's probably worth measuring how much of that time is taken up by the ~10 million random number generations.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker Good point. Ideone reports only 71ms though.

Comment: These are rather different jobs. I am not sure any comparison would be valid. `std::shuffle` is going to depend heavily on the random number generation algorithm. I would think swapping is very cheap and so is comparing two valies `a < b`. Generating random numbers, though, has to involve many more processing steps than `a < b`.

Comment: on my laptop, gcc gives these results : unoptimized [4109ms with 46947242 swaps, 1318ms with 9999999 swaps, 375ms with 9999999 rng], with `-O2` [794ms with 46992015 swaps, 461ms with 9999999 swaps, 194ms with 9999999 rng]. Both of these look very reasonable to me (ignoring the time taken for rng, the difference is a factor 3-4, which is very close to the factor 4-5 difference in number of swaps) - ie. I can't replicate your results here.

Comment: Did you compile with the Release configuration? I compiled with VS2013, release, the result is: 1005ms with 94135436 swaps
733ms with 9999999 swaps.  I did run several times, the result it the same: shuffle is faster

Comment: @Matt : the OP is surprised by the shuffle taking 5-10 times fewer swaps, yet not being 5-10 times faster.

Comment: @Matt It was faster for me as well, but as SanderDeDyker noted,  I was surprised by the ratio. And of course I used a release build :)

Comment: @SanderDeDyker, it's strange that such a simple rng took so much time in your case. Guess it's very implementation and hardware dependent. Thanks for testing though!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::random_shuffle` usually works as follows:

```
//random(k) generates uniform random from 0 to k-1 inclusive
for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  swap(arr[i], arr[random(i + 1)]);
```

So we can see two sources of inefficiency here:

1. Random number generators are often quite slow.
2. Each swap uses a totally random element from the vector. When the data size is large, the whole vector does not fit into CPU cache, so each such access has to wait until the data is read from RAM.

Speaking of point 2, sorting algorithms like quicksort are much more cache-friendly: most of their memory accesses hit cache.

Comment: Thanks! It seems to make sense. Note though that I consciously chose shuffle with very simple generator and not random_shuffle to avoid this influence. But thinking further to the implementation of sort, even the first partition will likely hit cache most of the time as there are two iterators moving linearly forward. Every swap in shuffle is very likely a cache miss. Thus the performance penalty. Thanks again, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @Rostislav: You might want to measure performance for lesser sizes of vector. Perhaps you will be able to see more.

Answer (score 2):

First, `std::sort` is not required to use an unqualified `swap`. It's not a customization point, and you cannot rely on your own user-defined `swap` being found through ADL. But even it would, `sort` can also use `std::rotate`, which can do `swap` but also `memmove`. This would not be counted by your implementation.

Second, the Standard Library only specifies asymptotic complexity, which is `O(N)` for `std::shuffle` and `O(N log N)` for `std::sort`. So you should measure for different values of `N` (e.g. powers of 2 from 65K to 65M amounts of elements) and measure the scaling behavior. For small `N`, the constant of proportionality of `sort` could be much smaller than the one for `shuffle` since it has to call a potentially expensive random generator.

**Update**: it indeed appears that constant factors and/or cache-effects are the culprit (as pointed out by @stgatilov). See [**this DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/87ee5af3dbfd6db5) where I run `std::sort` on the data after `std::shuffle` has been called. Runtime for `sort` is about half of that of `shuffle`, with 5x more swaps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I understand that there's no guarantee for swap to be used. However this is not my concern - it's picked up by current implementations of standard library which let's me count swaps -  that's enough for testing. And yes, the algorithmic complexity will probably have its effect for different sizes, but again it wouldn't answer my practical question -  why the observed behaviour is like it is for this particular case. Note that the results are similar for 100M elements on my machine as well.

Comment: @Rostislav if you look at [libc++](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/master/include/algorithm), it indeed uses unqualified `swap` in many places, but it also uses `while`-loops with `std::move` for contiguously moving data. So it's not *purely* swap-based and you would have to debug it to measure how much of the permutations are being swapped and how many are being  moved.

Comment: indeed. However, the thing is, unless shuffle doesn't use swap in some cases, the ratio of at least 5 is still there, so sort may do even more work than shuffle that I don't capture with my simple metric. Yet it is relatively fast. That was puzzling to me but it seems cache friendliness is the key.

Comment: @Rostislav to really isolate the cache-effects, why don't you try to measure `sort` on your data *after* it has been `shuffled`. So generate the data with `iota` (numbers 0 through 100M), then measure `shuffle`, then measure `sort`. Then you are guaranteed to have the same cache locality effects for both algorithms.

Comment: Great idea! Will try that as soon as I'm at my pc. If anything I feel it will be even more sort-favoured :) My feelings might be terribly wrong at the same time -  measurement is the king...

Comment: `std::sort` is allowed to call the client's `swap` via ADL, move construction and move assignment.  A poor but legal implementation can call `std::swap` (without using ADL) only because `std::swap` is only allowed to call a move construction and move assignment.  `std::shuffle` is *only* allowed to call `swap` via ADL (which may resolve to `std::swap` if there is no custom swap).  In all cases, `swap` *is* a "customization point."

Comment: @HowardHinnant I thought the term "customization point" was meant for those instances where the algorithm was *required* to call `swap` via ADL (like `shuffle`) and not just *allowed* to (as in `sort`)? How else can users rely on the customization point to call their custom code?

Comment: Well that's the problem with using terms that don't have an official definition in the standard. :-)  I consider `swap` a customization point because it can be a custom replacement for a std algorithm.  But the standard doesn't use this term.  It uses terms like:  "shuffle requires `Swappable`.  And then `Swappable` is rigorously defined to mean: calls your custom `swap` if you have one, else calls `std::swap`.  Some algorithms like `sort` say (I'm paraphrasing): Requires `Swappable`, `MoveConstructible` and `MoveAssignable`.  It is allowed to use any/all of these and nothing else.

Comment: In contrast, I don't consider `iter_swap` to be a customization point.  No where in the standard is there any wording that ever implies that an algorithm will call `iter_swap` via ADL, looking for your customization of it.

Comment: I regretfully consider `begin` and `end` customization points because range-for will sometimes look for them via ADL.  This is a design flaw in C++11 and later (imho) because it unnecessarily reserves the semantics of these short common words across all namespaces.